# ufs fails on debian

Tags: debian, system-installation, ext3, ufs

I am a longtime openSUSE user. However, my friend convinced me to give debian a try.

When installing, I noticed there was no ext3 option (which I usually use), so I selected ufs. Then I got an error:

> ufs file system creation failed.

I tried multiple times. It would seem that it only succeeded when I created only one partition (and not a seperate /home like I usually do).

Any ideas what went wrong here?

And why is there no ext3 option? Are people no longer using that? I thought they were.

Comment: [Debian still supports ext3.](http://wiki.debian.org/FileSystem)  What installer are you using?

Comment: Also if it lists ext4, that is a drop in replacement for ext3.

Comment: Hit Alt-F3 or Alt-F4, one of those consoles should have the log messages. That may give you a clue as to why mkfs failed. But really, use ext4.